# Jclouds Compute Service to run a shell script

Tags: chef-infra, rackspace-cloud, knife, jclouds

I had created a shell script using the ScriptBuilder on the Chef Workstation and was trying to run the shell script using the same. Basically I have a knife bootstrap command in the shell script.

```
computeService.runScriptOnNode(workstation.getId(), script, options)
```

And I get an error. But if I ssh into the box and execute the shell script manually it works. I might be missing something there.

My Shell Script looks like this ..I am using the root user so no sudo

```
Knife bootstrap 10.10.10.1 -x user -P pwd
```

And my scriptbuilder does the following at the end

```
sh ~/.chef/initialbootstrap.sh
```

Response Error #

```
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-cli-1.5.0/lib/mixlib/cli.rb:191:in `parse_options': invalid option: -x (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef   /application.rb:72:in `configure_chef'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/application.rb:59:in `reconfigure'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/application.rb:49:in `block in initialize'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `call'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/knife/cookbook_delete.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:34:in `load'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:34:in `block in load_commands'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:34:in `each'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader.rb:34:in `load_commands'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/knife.rb:120:in `load_commands'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/knife.rb:168:in `run'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:135:in `run'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/bin/knife:23:in `load'
from /usr/bin/knife:23:in `<main>'
```

Not sure what is happening. I am new to Chef / jclouds / Ruby ..

Comment: I'm confused by these lines in the stacktrace:

`from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/application.rb:49:in 'block in initialize'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'call'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/knife/cookbook_delete.rb:19:in '<top (required)>'`

That line in cookbook_delete.rb does a `require 'chef/knife'`, which shouldn't do anything because `chef/knife.rb` is already loaded.

Comment: Is it possible that the trace output is being mangled somehow?